# Airflow daily schedule won't trigger, but other schedule does

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have couple of DAGs which I am currently running to pull the data.
DAGs with schedules like 5 Minutes, 15 minutes, Hourly, 12 hours etc. All of these DAGs are scheduled on time.
BUT the DAGs with Daily schedule wont trigger.
I did check the Scheduler logs and I don't see any entries/errors for the daily DAGs.

Did try

1. `timedelta(minutes=24*60)` `timedelta(days=24*60)` values for start_date arg
2. `airflow resetdb`
3. did try the start_date for dag to days_ago() and specific time tooo.

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': days_ago(0),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False
}

dag = DAG(
    TASK,
    default_args=default_args,
    description='test dag',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=24*60),
)

splunk_pull = PythonOperator(
    task_id=TASK,
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=test_splunk,
    op_kwargs={'usecase': 'predict'},
    dag=dag,
    execution_timeout=timedelta(minutes=120)
)
```

The Airflow Image I am using is `puckel/docker-airflow:latest`
Version `Version : 1.10.9`

Comment: Is the dag unpaused? Are you sure that the daily DAG has different dag_id than others?

Comment: Yes, Its unpaused and the ID is unique.
I did try creating different filenames and different dag_ids too

Comment: using days_ago(1) and schedule_interval = '@daily' should work

Comment: why not using cron syntax like this: '0 0 * * *`. This will trigger the DAG at the start of the day every day.  You can set other hour and minute as you want

Comment: I'd go with @JavierLópezTomás option. Read more about schedule nuances for DAG run [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/dag-run.html#dag-runs).